# R Get collapsed counts - ctable and table don't give me what i'm looking for

Tags: r

Using mtcars, I'd like to get a collapsed counting of am, gear, and carb.  The first few rows look like this:

```
am  gear carb
1   4     4
1   4     4
1   4     1
0   3     1
0   3     2
0   3     1
0   3     4
0   4     2
0   4     2
```

And i want to get output that looks like this:

```
am  gear carb   Count
0   3     1      2
0   3     2      1
0   3     4      1
0   4     2      2
1   4     1      1
1   4     4      2
```

Both table and ctable (summarytools) do some weird thing where it runs all the numbers out and that's not what i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      count(am, gear, carb)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#     am  gear  carb     n
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     0     3     1     2
#2     0     3     2     1
#3     0     3     4     1
#4     0     4     2     2
#5     1     4     1     1
#6     1     4     4     2
```

Or

```
df1 %>%
    group_by_all() %>%
    summarise(Count = n())
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(am = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gear = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), carb = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Comment: Oh, quick followup.  It worked great on real data, but now i hit this.  I still got what i wanted, so i'm not certain it's an issue, but should i care about this?





````Factor 'lsscm_outcomes2' contains implicit NA, consider using 'forcats::fct_explicit_na'

Comment: @getoffmylap  Try by converting the columns to `character` class and run it again

Comment: well that's what they were.  I have the original data, i'm converting it to factor, and then i want compare the before and after and make sure nothing got missed.  Which means i want a collapsed count of both.  With different data types i guess since that's how R does stuff.

Comment: @getoffmylap  Can you please update the post or post as a new question as I am not following it correctly

Comment: Oh i don't have a new question. In fact finding this count thing has made my life infinitely more awesome when it comes to R!!!  I was just saying in response to your comment to convert to character, that's what a lot of them originally are.  I've imported a file from Excel and recoded variables to factor so i can add value labels.  But then i want to compare the original with the new to make sure I didn't miss anything.  Text v factor.  So i've just started ignoring the warning message b/c i still get exactly what i want to see and that's what's important to me.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

With base R, you can also do this:

```
as.data.frame(table(df1))
```

And to filter non-occurring combinations:

```
freqs <- as.data.frame(table(df1))
freqs[freqs$Freq > 0,]
```